# urllib2.Request freezes sometimes

Tags: python, urllib

I have following code to parse the website:

```
if os.path.isfile(data_content_file):
    try:
        with open(data_content_file) as data_file:    
            question_answer = json.load(data_file)
    except Exception as e:
        question_answer = {}
else:
    question_answer = {}

if os.path.isfile(count_file):
    f = open(count_file, 'r')
    try:
        start = int(f.read())
    except Exception as e:
        start = 1
    f.close()
else:
    start = 1

f = open(count_file, 'w+')
for x in xrange(start,500000):
    try:
        print(x)
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(x))
        req = urllib2.Request("https://islamqa.info/en/"+str(x), headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
        con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(con.read(),"lxml")
```

I don't know why it get freezed at some x values.

If I stop my script and run again for the same x value, it runs fine.

I tried using timeout, but it's not loading any page, even if timeout is 1000:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://islamqa.info/en/"+str(x), headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"},timeout=10000)
```

What's the best way to avoid this, or continue the loop, even the site freezes.

Comment: Interesting question. It could be that there is no clean way to abort it if the server never responds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817337/how-do-i-gracefully-interrupt-urllib2-downloads

Comment: (Also, one reason the server might just not respond is if they are actively trying to prevent you from requesting so many pages in quick succession)

Comment: Can't I get any status from server? Morever, yesterday I parsed the whole website in almost one go. Today, I am facing some issues.

Comment: For HTTP in Python, the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module is usually a better option than the various `urllib` versions.

Comment: Your comment answers my question.