# Progress update while downloading and interpreting json

Tags: python, json, urllib

Is there a way to get a progress update while downloading and interpreting json data?

Right now I'm using this to get data into my program:

```
url_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(url_data)
```

For larger data-sets both lines can take several seconds or even minutes. So I would like to show some kind of progress bar to the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028517/python-urllib2-progress-hook

Comment: this helps with the first part, thanks